# Trying to create a login form using dapper to connect to SQL but I can't get the DataAdapter to work

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my code

```
public class LoginFunction
{
    public DataTable User (string username, string pword)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionHelper.CnnVal("GymDB")))
        {

            var query = ("Select * from [USER] where username = '{username}'  and password = '{pword}'");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);



        }
    }
}
```

}

The error im getting is "cannot convert from 'System.Data.IDbConnection' to 'string'".

The error is with the connection argument for SqlDataAdapter - I thought this would get the SQL connection from the IDbConnection.

Comment: There is no Dapper code there.

Comment: @codeulike I thought the IDbconnection line was Dapper code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry I can not comment yet.

Try to change `IDbConnection` to `SqlConnection` and `var query` to `string query` and take away the parenthesis.

See if it works!?